# Spring Boot 1.0.0-RC4 starts with multiple EmbeddedServletContainerFactory instances

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I am looking to override the default EmbeddedServletContainerFactory as documented [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html) in order to set up SSL.  The [old docs](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/docs/howto.html) (from RC1 days) said to override the Customizer and that worked great until I upgraded today, changed the implementation to follow the new convention.

```
@Configuration
public class ContainerConfig {

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
  factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {

  @Override
  public void customize(Connector connector) {

    connector.setPort(8443);
    connector.setSecure(true);
    connector.setScheme("https");
    connector.setAttribute("keyAlias", "tomcat");
    connector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "changeit");
    try {
      connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", ResourceUtils.getFile("src/ssl/tomcat.keystore").getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot load keystore", e);
    }
      connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
      connector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
      connector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
    }

  });

  factory.setSessionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

  return factory;
}
```

The source code in Boot (EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration) indicates that if it does find my bean, it will not register the default:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
```

However it appears to register anyhow.  Does anybody else have this working?  Here is the stack:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start embedded container; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to multiple
>   EmbeddedServletContainerFactory beans :
>   servletContainer,tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:619)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:880)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:869)
>     at
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:
>   Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to multiple
>   EmbeddedServletContainerFactory beans :
>   servletContainer,tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
>     ... 12 more

I have created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/hoserdude/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-ssl) that mashes up the Tomcat and Websocket samples from the Spring Boot project, and applies this configuration.

Comment: That should work (and the link to the docs is up to date, although it is a different pattern to the one you implemented, since it doesn't actually create a `@Bean` of type `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`). Can you share a project?

Comment: Thanks for responding Dave, I can reproduce by putting together the tomcat and websockets samples - as soon as spring-boot-starter-websocket is a dependency this happens, probably because of some auto-config related to web sockets and the container.  I can post my mashup of the two samples if that helps.

Comment: It is indeed the `WebSocketAutoConfiguration` that is the culprit, it looks like detecting existing `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` beans prior to creating one in this class might be the trick, I will experiment and put a pull request in if it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is a (sort of) bug (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/479). Fixed now. Workaround is to use `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` instead of `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` (like in the docs link in the original question).